# Find the least upper bound and greatest lower bound for {$x : x^3 \ge 8 $}

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

The notation {$x : x^3 \ge 8 $} confuses me a bit. Am I understanding this right? It's asking which x is the smallest that are great than or equal to 8?

If I'm understanding the question then there is no lub right because there are an infinite set of numbers greater than 8. And would the greatest lower bound (glb) be 2 since $8^\frac13$ would be the smallest number?

Comment: Not quite. It's the set of $x$ such that $x^3$ is greater than or equal to $8$.

Comment: Your answers are correct.

Comment: Anyway, an infinite number pf elements never  meant no sup. Counter example: $[0,1]$ is  has the cardinality of $\mathbf R$.

Comment: In general it's important to know from which set $x$ is and over which set you're considering glb and lub  (here it's probably assumed $\Bbb{R} $) , often written something like $\{x \in \Bbb{R} : x^3\geq 8\} $ or $\{x : x\in\Bbb{R}, x^3\geq 8\} $. Here for example if the set was irrational numbers for both $x$ and glb/lub then there wouldn't be a glb because $2$ isn't irrational and irrational numbers are dense in $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set $S=\{x: x^3 \geq 8\}$ is unbounded above, so mathematicans would tend to write $sup(S)=\infty$.

We also have $inf(S)=2$ because $min(S)=2$. (Every element of $S$ is $\geq2$, and $2 \in S$, hence $min(S)$ exists and $=2$.)

Comment: Saying $sup(S)= \infty$ is the same as saying "there is no upper bound so no least upper bound".

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\{x : x^3 \ge 8 \}$ defines by property the set such that $x^3\ge 8$ that is

$$[2,\inf)$$